# c# StreamWriter disposal - return underlying MemoryStream (open)

Tags: c#

except for the comments here ( [MemoryStream disables reading when returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528697/memorystream-disables-reading-when-returned][1]) ), I haven't found a good answer to my concerns about leaving a StreamWriter open. I would like to return a MemoryStream (open) that is written by a StreamWriter **in a safe and clean way**.

Let me give a rather simple example.
I would like to use the Method **GetMemoryStream()** like this:

```
        String[] content = { "large", "string", "array", "test" };
        MemoryStream ms = GetMemoryStream(content);
        //byte[] array = ms.ToArray(); //still works after stream is closed but I want an open and working stream.
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            //fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length); 
            ms.WriteTo(fs);
        }
        ms.Dispose();
```

Now here are two ways I found to do so:

1. Copy the MemoryStream

   ```
   public static MemoryStream GetMemoryStream(String[] content)
   {
       MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
       {
           foreach (String s in content)
               sw.WriteLine(s);
           sw.Flush();
           ms.CopyTo(result);
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

This aproach looks like a workaround to me. It seems (correct me if I'm wrong) to need twice as much memory and more time. Then I read about the next aproach:

2. Leave the StreamWriter Open (>=.Net 4.5)

   ```
   public static MemoryStream GetMemoryStream(String[] content)
   {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.Default, 1024, true))
        {
             foreach (String s in content)
                  sw.WriteLine(s);
        }
        return ms;
   }
   ```

But I have concerns with that aproach:

> What happens to the StreamWriter when I leave the scope?
>   Is the data still referenced/held by that StreamWriter object?
>   Will it be garbage-collected? Maybe even before I get to use the MemoryStream in
>   the calling scope?
>   Is it still "connected" to the MemoryStream, and maybe disposed when I dispose ms?

To sum it up: Is the second aproach going to cause any trouble?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are correctly using `using` in the second approach. You should not be worried about these things when you are correctly using `using`. This is why `using` exists in the first place.

Comment: Go through the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose to understand about disposal in depth.

Comment: @HansPassant - "disposing the StreamWriter disposes the MemoryStream as well" - when they're already passing `true` as the `leaveOpen` parameter to the `StreamWriter` constructor?

Comment: The second piece of code is correct, it will leave the underlying stream undisposed because of the `leaveOpen` parameter being `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. @Hans Passant, I am already using the ctor that leaves the memorystream open. But I want it to get closed after I dispose the returned MemoryStream. Not to early though... I am afraid the StreamWriter will get garbage collected before using/disposing the MemoryStream.

Comment: If the `StreamWriter` is collected this will not impact the `MemoryStream` at all since there is no finalizer in `StreamWriter`. Additionally, `MemoryStream` is a managed reference which such a finalizer shouldn't touch anyway.

Comment: So, the disposal of the StreamWriter (with "leave open") will just "detach" the underlying MemoryStream, leaving no reference to the StreamWriter.(?) Thats what I wanted to here. :D (I will read further into the GC, thanks for the link)

Comment: The `MemoryStream` knows nothing about the `StreamWriter`, regardless of what you pass for `leaveOpen` or which constructor on `StreamWriter` you use.

Comment: Got it now, thanks. In the end I was confused by MemoryStream.Close() done by StreamWriter.Dispose().

Comment: And you don't need the sw.Flush().  That too is taking care of by the `using{}`.

Comment: Thanks @bommelding, that might be true, can you post a link with prove? I always wanted to see stuff like that in the docs, but I don't know where to look. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.dispose?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: It's just a few clicks from that german page you linked to. But it is spread out over about 3 pages.

Comment: "A few clicks away"?(... To the left or to the right?) If you got the link would you please be so kind and post it?     Sorry for the german link, google/browser/site decides the language, I gave up trying... you could "disable german" with a "slide switch" at the top-right of that page.

Comment: You go from StreamWiter.Dispose to Stream.Dispose to Stream.Close.

Comment: Thanks, I could find the answer in Stream.Flush(). As for Stream.Close() they write stuff about flushing in common but there is not explit "Close will flush"-Sentence. I will edit answer and question now.

Answer (score 1):

So after reading the comments of my Question, its safe to use this aproach:

```
String[] content = { "large", "string", "array", "test" };
MemoryStream ms = GetMemoryStream(content);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
   ms.WriteTo(fs);
}
ms.Dispose();
```

--

```
public static MemoryStream GetMemoryStream(String[] content)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.Default, 1024, true))
    {
        foreach (String s in content)
            sw.WriteLine(s);
    }
    return ms;
}
```

My concerns that there will be "leftovers" (references, blocking-memory, ...) of that StreamWriter were wrong. The StreamWriter gets fully disposed, but it wont touch/dispose the underlying MemoryStream when using that ctor. (please correct me when I am still wrong.)

Thanks to all

Comment: When you're "nesting" streams, it's normal (as here) that the inner stream has *no knowledge* of which streams have been wrapped around it. The `StreamWriter` has a reference to the `Stream` you passed in the constructor (not knowing what type of stream it even is). There aren't references in the other direction.

Comment: Yes thanks. I guess what troubled my tired brain in the first place was that the disposal of StreamWriter also closed the underlying Stream. I thought they were somehow "bound" to each other, but its just "bad" design of the StreamWriter Class then, isn't it?

Comment: in a lot of cases (mostly streams other than memory streams) it's the right thing to do; So I don't think it's a bad *default* and at least it's changeable.

Comment: As long as its possible to prevent the close() I agree. But afaik that was not possible before .Net4.5. (You could maybe inherit StreamWriter to prevent that, but when thats not possible ... I am back to my first aproach) Either way, thanks for the input. =)

Answer (score 0):

A using scope is a syntactic sugar of try-finally block, equal to the code below, Dispose method is implicitly called.

```
StreamWriter sw;
try
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.Default, 1024, true);
    foreach (String s in content)
        sw.WriteLine(s);
}
finally
{
    if(sw != null)
        sw.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thats true, but didn't quite match my (maybe not well formed/precise) question.