# Custom MedaTypeFormatter Causes ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, streamwriter, disposable

I have a custom formatter to support my web calls, but a bug report shed some light on an issue.  I was overriding the `WriteToStreamAsync()` method as such:

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type,
                                        object value,
                                        Stream writeStream,
                                        HttpContent content,
                                        TransportContext transportContext)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
            {
                var serialized = _serializer.Serialize(value);
                sw.Write(serialized);
            }
        });
}
```

According to [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1775891.aspx?Using+custom+MediaTypeFormatter+causing+test+to+hang), the issue was that the `using` statement was causing the stream to close.  The solution was to remove the `using` statement and use an explicit `Flush()` call, but it feels wrong to depend on the GC to dispose of the `StreamWriter`.

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type,
                                        object value,
                                        Stream writeStream,
                                        HttpContent content,
                                        TransportContext transportContext)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            var sw = new StreamWriter(writeStream);
            var serialized = _serializer.Serialize(value);
            sw.Write(serialized);
            sw.Flush();
        });
}
```

1. Is this a major concern?
2. Is there a better (more "best practice") way of doing this?

Comment: Are you asking of how to properly close `StreamWriter` without closing its base stream? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2666888/1997232).

Comment: @sinatr, yes, I think that would be ideal.

Comment: Click the Click (in previous comment), hopefully you can use .Net 4.5.

Comment: @Sinatr, answer and you can score some rep!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a major concern?

No, if the `Stream` survives the reader and it is clear, who is responsible for disposing the stream.

It is common in the .NET Framework, too. For example, if an `Icon` is created from a `Stream`, you must not dispose it (do not use the `using` construct when you create the icon) because it will be used by the created instance.

> Is there a better (more "best practice") way of doing this?

- If you create both the `Stream` and the `StreamWriter` in the same scope, the story is clear, you can dispose them.
- If you get an already existing `Stream`, you cannot be sure that you are allowed to dispose the `Stream`. Do not close it unless the documentation is clear about that.