# XmlDictionaryWriter closes the output stream when disposed, .NET Portable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

My context is .NET PCL Profile111.

I try to use the `DataContractSerializer` with `XmlDictionaryWriter` for binary xml serialization. The problem I have is that after I dispose of the `XmlDictionaryWriter` the `MemoryStream` it was writing to gets closed.
My code:

```
using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(outputStream))
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(iObject.GetType());
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, iObject);
    writer.Flush();
}

//outputStream is closed now.
```

Documentation for the [XmlWriterSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the [CloseOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.closeoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) property is **false** by default.

I cannot use the overload for `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter` with `ownsStream` parameter because it is not available in PCL.

How can I make the `XmlDictionaryWriter` let the output `Stream` live after the `XmlDictionaryWriter` is disposed?

Comment: No idea how to achieve that, but you are mistaking one thing. The `CloseOutput` property is a setting for behaviour when `Close` method is called. Not `Dispose`. Probably the proper implementation of `IDisposable` in this class required to close the `Stream`. I would do it like that if I were the author. Also, why would you want to do that? Maybe there is an alternative way to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: @Peuczyński I looked into the `XmlDictionaryWriter.Dispose` source code, it's inherited from `XmlWriter` and just calls the `Close` method inside.

Comment: that's what I thought. You haven't told what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Peuczyński Didn't I? This is the last phrase in the question:

How can I make the XmlDictionaryWriter let the output Stream live?

Comment: yup, but why? I don't think that will be possible so I want to know is there any other way to help you. Actually I have an idea, give me a few minutes

Comment: @Peuczyński I need that because the serialization code is in one place and the stream is sent to a server via HTTP chunked transfer in another place. While the transfer is in place, I am going to append data into the stream.

Comment: Why can't you just do [`XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(outputStream, null, null, false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: @dbc I could if I used full .NET, unfortunately this overload is unavailable in PCL. I am sorry I forgot to mention that I am limited to PCL, editing.

Comment: That's surprising, since the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say ***Portable Class Library**:
Supported in: [portable .NET platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)*.  And the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Xml/XmlDictionaryWriter.cs,a4762dfe30620647,references) doesn't show any conditional compilation.

Comment: @dbc Yeah. Looks like it is available in some PCL profiles, but not the one I am limited to.

Comment: In that case, same advice as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2666906) for `StreamWriter`: 1) flush but don't dispose the `XmlDictionaryWriter`.  Unlike dispose, the finalize method will **not** dispose the underlying stream.  2) Create a wrapper for `Stream` that, when disposed, does not dispose the underlying stream.

Comment: @dbc Wrapper for the MemoryStream...that could work. Post this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the overload [`XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(outputStream, null, null, false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is unavailable on your version of the PCL, you have a couple of options similar to those described in [Is there any way to close a StreamWriter without closing its BaseStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2666906):

1. You can flush but not dispose the `XmlDictionaryWriter` and leave it to the GC to clean up.  Unlike the `Dispose()` method, the finalization method will *not* dispose the underlying stream.
2. Create a wrapper `Stream` for your stream that, when disposed, does not dispose the underlying stream.  E.g. Jon Skeet has `NonClosingStreamWrapper` in his [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option would be own implementation of `XmlDictionaryWriter` class.

That may seem hard, but all you have to do is create 2 new classes:
`PersistentXmlDictionaryWriter` that is exactly like [this one](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Xml/XmlDictionaryWriter.cs,60dd75fd0ec1aee9) but instead of deriving from `XmlWriter` would derive from your new class `PersisternXmlWriter` that would be exaxtly like [this one](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriter.cs,e5032b905808fabc) but you would change the Dispose method not to close the stream.

That should do it.

Comment: This way I would fork myself out of updates made to the .NET BinaryXmlWriter. This is too dangerous thing to do in the matters of serialization.

Comment: I don't see any other way to do it. If you are trying to do something that differs from the standard approach you have to create your own classes. I don't see any other possible solutions, and we'be both seen the source code.

Comment: It is not something non-standard. Actually, `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter` has an overload with explicit flag i.e. ownsStream which does what I need but it is not available for PCL.

Comment: When I said non-standard I meant that you're trying to change the natural behaviour of a class. It's like saying teaching cat to bark is not non-standard because another four legged animal has the ability. I hope I am clear this time. Basically, if you try to change some internal piece of code for a class, there is no other way. I tried playing with creating the class deriving from `Stream` and then providing it to the `XmlDictionaryWriter` but then I ended up with the problem of not having constructor that would accept `Stream` as argument and creating it would be basically writing new class.

Comment: Again, XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter is designed to treat the stream as an external asset. This is it's natural behaviour. Teaching a cat to bark is something very different.

Comment: Now I get it. I was referring to the current state, and you were referring to how it suppose to work (as it isn't suppose to dispose of a provided stream). All clear now.