# NancyFx: Are streams disposed when using StreamResponse()?

Tags: c#, stream, nancy

Are streams disposed in NancyFx when using StreamResponse()?

Using a streamWriter to write to the stream, I can't dispose of it without closing the stream I want to send out. And the way I see it, I can't dispose of the stream manually either since I effectively left the method at the return.

This code works:

```
// Open a stream and write to it with streamReader
Stream memStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter memWriter = new StreamWriter(memStream, Encoding.UTF8);
memWriter.Write(someStringText);
memWriter.Flush();
memStream.Position = 0;

// Add stream to the respose which should get downloaded
var response = new StreamResponse(() => memStream, MimeTypes.GetMimeType(contentType));
return response.AsAttachment(someFileName);
```

Do I need to worry about the stream lingering on until the garbage collector comes along or do it get disposed correctly by the StreamResponse?

Comment: If that class implement IDisposable, then dispose it, if you are finish with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`StreamResponse.cs`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Responses/StreamResponse.cs), `StreamResponse.Dispose()` disposes of the stream returned by the `Func<Stream>`, and Nancy handles disposing the `Response` at the end of the `NancyContext`.

As for disposing of `StreamWriter` without affecting the underlying stream, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666888/60188).

Comment: And the streamWriter can safely be managed by the garbage collector? I see no way to handle that without closing the stream.

Comment: When is StreamResponse.Dispose() called though? Is that handled by Nancy, or do we need to call it explicitly?