# Stream content as Azure function output

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am working with some files and converting from one format to another. My function is a step in a logic app and the output of my function results in a file being created, using the pre-defined step "Create file (FTP)" where the file content is the body of my function.

I am trying to change the way my function works at the moment to have a memory friendly version. I was trying to achieve some form of 'streaming' so that I essentially only have one object in memory at a given time when deserializing.

I have tried something along the lines of the below and while it doesn't throw any errors I am not getting the expected output.

```
[FunctionName("Transform")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Import([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{

    var doc = XDocument.Load(await req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    if (doc.Root != null)
    {
        var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var query = from c in doc.Descendants(ns + "person")
                    select c;

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        var persons = new List<Person>();

        foreach (var Person in query)
        {
            var personRecord = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(person.CreateReader());
            persons.Add(personRecord);
        }


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(persons);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            memoryStream.Flush();
        }
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream)
    };
}
```

When I debug my function locally and make a request to it via Postman I simply get a "could not load response". I was, if all worked well, expecting something like a csv output e.g.

```
John, Doe, 123
Mary, Jane, 456
```

I am wondering if the idea is good at all? At least that's what I am thinking at the moment, I just can't figure out how to do it.

Cheers

Comment: your memorystream is closed when returning. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666888/is-there-any-way-to-close-a-streamwriter-without-closing-its-basestream)

Comment: Thank you @Tewr, it helped me get to a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're using `StreamWriter` is causing the `MemoryStream` to be disposed of. By default the `StreamWriter` assumes ownership of the `Stream` it is handed and will dispose of it when it is disposed (or GC'd).

You'll need to use the constructor overload that takes `(Stream, Encoding, int, bool)` where the `bool` is named `leaveOpen` and you need to set that to `true`. I had to double check, but there is no simpler overload of just `(Stream, bool)`. You'd probably want to do something like:

```
new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8Encoding, bufferSize:8192, leaveOpen:true)
```

However you should really decide what encoding works best for you and what `bufferSize` might make the most sense for your workload.