# Properly Disposing StreamWriter by use of using statement

Tags: c#, using

Inside a `using` I'm generating a `Stream`:

```
using (var generatedStream = GenerateStream(str))
{
    var streamContent = generatedStream;
}
```

`GenerateStream(string s)` looks like this:

```
private static Stream GenerateStream(string s)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

When I get to assigning `generatedStream` to `streamContent`, more specifically, when I exit the `using` statement in `GenerateStream`, it says that `stream` is disposed. What am I doing wrong in making sure I dispose my writer?

UPDATE:

The solution posted in the linked question seems to be the way to go for this particular problem.

Comment: The problem is that inside `GenerateStream` you dispose `writer`, which in turn disposes `stream` because `StreamWriter` takes control of that underlying stream. I remember there have been ways to tell `StreamWriter` not to do that, but I just can't find them...

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2666906/1009661

Comment: @RenéVogt that would be the linked duplicate post I believe

Comment: @Rahul yep, that's it. In the other constructors I found that take a bool, that bool was used to indicate append- or overwrite mode...thatswhy I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

The using statement in your method `GenerateStream()` shouldn't be present

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

the using statement helps in disposing the stream already. It disposes at the end of the code block.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement