# Is there any relation between stream & streamreader/streamwriter & string in c#?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter, memorystream

I have a library that uses `StreamWriter` to write a string into a `Stream`. I need it to write that string into a NOT FILE stream like `MemoryStream`. But when I try to read from that `MemoryStream` using a `StreamReader` I get an "Stream was not readable" error. Can anyone help?

The code is something like this:

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            sw.Write("hello");
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

The library code is:

```
    public void Save(Stream jsonStream)
    {
        if (jTokenValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(jsonStream))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(jTokenValue.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll give you a hint: when you have `using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))`, as soon as that `using` closes, it will close the stream writer, which *closes the underlying stream* unless you tell it not to.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666888/is-there-any-way-to-close-a-streamwriter-without-closing-its-basestream

Comment: As @Amy commented code you have closes the stream and linked as duplicate question explains what can be done about it. I'd strongly recommend to rethink `Save(Stream)` method - if you expect implementations to use `StreamWriter` it would be better to start with `Save(StreamWriter)` otherwise you continue running into this "operation on disposed object" error all the time when one writes (or "fixes") code with regular `using(StreamWriter …)` logic.

Comment: Added a better duplicate for the context

Comment: public static void Demo()
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                sw.Write("hello");
                sw.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }